# Regarding connecting to the lavvideo.ax

Tags: directshow

I have one source filter(implementing IFileSource) which reads rtsp stream, and it has video and audio outpins.
If I add this filter into graphstudio and  connect it's video output pin to LAVVideo.ax, it worked.

But if I add it to my graph,and connect it to LAVVideo.ax, it crashes's in LAVVideo.ax.
So I don't implement IFileSource, then connect it to LAVVideo.ax, it worked. But in such case,
the video would occur mosaic.
Does the special settings needs to be set when the source filter implements the IFileSource?

Comment: Are there any error messages when it crashes?

Comment: Is it a sourcefilter you wrote? Maybe there is a problem with the MediaType from the Video-Pin (h264 missing SPS and PPS). What video/audio codecs are transmittet? Are there any specific error messages? Maybe you need to wait a little after initialising the source filter (network operations can be a little slow sometimes).

Comment: I can't understand if I don't implement IFileSourceFilte, then it connect successfully.